# Writing very large pandas dataframe into a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a very large pandas dataframe with 7.2 million rows. When I'm trying to write it into a csv file using `df.to_csv` only around 1.6 million rows are getting written into the file. How can I write the complete data into csv file? Even if it is not possible to write in csv, can I write it to any other format that can be opened in excel?

Comment: I think `1.6` million rows is the limit of Excel, not csv.

Comment: I would suggest partitioning it into multiple files if that is possible.

Comment: Excel tops out at just over a million rows... don't use it to open large CSVs.

Comment: @BigBen is correct, [Microsoft's doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) says `1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns`. You should look for something else or break your data in smaller pieces.